# Bluetooth 5 headphones stop playing sound while using multipoint with a phone

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have Bluetooth 5 headphones, connected to my Ubuntu (using PulseAudio) with multipoint to my phone. But every time I'm unlocking the phone / the notification arrives to it - the headphones don't play any sound from Ubuntu, but playback didn't pause and default output devices do not change.

The only thing that fixes it - is to change the profile from A2DP to HSP, and back again.

Comment: That's how it works, apparently.

Comment: @ChanganAuto In the case of switching devices, shouldn't it pause playback on the current device and switch to the next one? I don't really think that toggling profiles, or completely reconnecting device is the real way to go in that case

Comment: I think the problem is the phone switching modes even if only briefly.